# How can I bypass or temporarily disable some of mandatory(required) fields in ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have created a ViewModel with data validations defined. In some of my Views I want to remove the Required validation on some of the fields. I want to avoid creating duplicate ViewModel just for the sake of two fields. Now my question is, If there is a way in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages/MVC where I can bypass or temporarily disable some fields before I perform

```
ModelState.IsValid
```

I found few examples where they are using ModelState.Remove

```
  ModelState.Remove("Decision.Crfile");
  ModelState.Remove("Decision.DecisionFile");

  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
  }
```

But in that case the validation is not working on other fields as well..

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: As opposed to creating complete duplicates, is there a reason why you wouldn't use inheritance here against a common base model with all of the shared fields?